# GitHub workflow : one job for each different git actions (push on master, push tags...)

Tags: github, github-actions

I would like to setup my workflow to do the following:

- On any event (pull-request, push on any branches)

  - Checkout code
  - Build project
  - Run tests
  - Upload artifacts for other jobs
- Only when master is pushed

  - Download artifacts from previous job
  - Push GH-pages
- Only when a tag is pushed

  - Download artifacts from previous job
  - Create a release
  - Upload artifacts to the release

In my `.github/workflows` the `on` directives applies to all jobs so it won't work in my case. On the other hand, the `action/upload-artifact` only works within the same workflow.

What is the proper way to achieve the described workflow?

```
on: push
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v1
        with:
          submodules: true
      - name: Build
        run: make all
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: build
          path: dist/
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        filters: # <-----<<<< What I would like to do
          branch: master                
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@3.5.9
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN  }}
          BRANCH: gh-pages
          FOLDER: dist/html
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could add conditions to your steps and simply skip parts which aren't needed, see [`jobs.<id>.steps.if`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsif). As for *what* to check, `github` context is a goldmine of various data related to currently running workflow. For example

```
github.event_name  string  The name of the event that triggered the workflow run.
github.ref         string  The branch or tag ref that triggered the workflow run.
github.head_ref    string  The head_ref or source branch of the pull request in a workflow run.
```

and so on.

Just a note that parts [mentioned in documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context) are just a tip of an iceberg; `github.event` contains wall of useful stuff. It's best to [take a look](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#example-printing-context-information-to-the-log-file) in some test workflow and see what each event provides.

---

Something like that should work:

```yaml
- name: On any event (pull-request, push on any branches) 
  uses: some/action
```

```yaml
- name: Only when master is pushed
  if:   github.event_name == 'push' && github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'
  uses: some/action
```

```yaml
- name: Only when a tag is pushed 
  if:   github.event_name == 'push' && startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/')
  uses: some/action
```